# eval: Symbol’s function definition is void: org-macro--get-property

Tags: org-mode, tangle

I am trying to tangle an org file, but this error shows up even if I invoke the command with an emacs -Q instance. Google does not seem to yield anything useful here. Can anyone help me get to the cause of this?

Comment: `emacs -Q -l org-macro` will load the `org-macro.el[c]` library and provide the definition of `org-macro--get-property`.

Comment: thanks! How can I avoid having to invoke this flag everytime?

Comment: I suspect that this question is a duplicate. There have been lots of void-fun-definition questions, and some of them have been due to not loading the library that defines the function. Could someone please look for a dup, and close this if it's a dup? Thx.

Comment: It depends on where the problem comes from. The simplest thing to do is to add `(require 'org-macro)` to your init file and invoke emacs without the -Q so that the init file is actually used. But if you had a problem before when you were using your init file, then it might be better to investigate and fix the problem. It may be just a simple reordering that is needed, but there is very little information given in your question to be able to debug the problem remotely.